# OCI compute instance failed to start

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a oci node which I am stopping using oci cli command`oci compute instance action --action STOP --instance-id <instanceid>`
After few hours I am starting the node using command `oci compute instance action --action START --instance-id <instanceid>`

The start command failed with error

> ServiceError:
> {
> "code": "Conflict",
> "message": "instance  is currently being modified, try again later",
> "opc-request-id": "",
> "status": 409
> }

This was working few days back, but from last day i got this error. Any idea why this happened?

Comment: Does starting the instance via the OCI console (browser) work? What lifecycle state is the instance in when you start it and it fails with this error?

Comment: @Vineeth NG - Is this still happening? Were you able to resolve it?